# Creating a Function that writes to a file in Powershell

Tags: powershell

So in powershell I know how to write to a file by either using ">test.txt" or by using Out-File but I'm trying to create a function in Powershell.

```
function Create New Nuspec { out-file test.txt
            <id>$id</id>
            <authors>CME</authors>
            <owners>CME</owners>
            <version>$version</version>
            <description>$filepath</desciption>
            }
```

So I'm trying to have this function output to a file, eventually an XML file but for now I'm just trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
function CreateNewNuspec { 
param ($outfile, $id, $version, $filepath)

@"
<id>$id</id>
<authors>CME</authors>
<owners>CME</owners>
<version>$version</version>
<description>$filepath</description>
"@ | Out-File $outfile
}

CreateNewNuspec test.txt "ID1" "1.0" "filename.txt"
```