# Access to Path is Denied Powershell

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

right now I have just set my environment variable and am trying to have the file output to the Temp directory. Every time I run the batch file though it says that access to pathway is denied, below is the entirety of my code

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
         ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true,
         HelpMessage="List of files to add to the package")]
[String] $File

)

Function CreateNugetPackage {
    Param(
        [String] $File
    )
    Process {
        $retCode = 0
        write-verbose "Getting ID, Version, and Filepath of $file..."
        $version = (Get-Item $File).VersionInfo.FileVersion
        $id = $file.Substring(0, $File.LastIndexof('.'))
        $filepath = Get-ChildItem "$File"
        $netVer = ildasm /text $File| findstr Metadata
        $netVerShort = $netVer.Substring(0, $netVer.IndexOf('.') + 1 +   $netVer.Substring($netVer.IndexOf('.') + 1).IndexOf('.'))
        $netVerConv = @{
        'v2.0' = "lib\net20";
        '// Metadata version: v2.0' = "lib\net20";
        'v3.0' = "lib\net30";
        'v3.5' = "lib\net35";
        'v4.0' = "lib\net40";
        'v4.5' = "lib\net45";
        }
        $target = $netVerConv.Get_Item($netVerShort)
        $OriginalFilename = (Get-Item $File).VersionInfo.OriginalFilename
        write-verbose "$id"
        write-verbose "$version"
        write-verbose "$filepath"
        write-verbose "$netVer"
        write-verbose "$netVerShort"
        write-verbose "$target"
        function CreateNewNuspec { 
            param ($File)
            $x=
           "<?xml version=""1.0""?>
            <package xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd"">
            <metadata>
                <id>$id</id>
                <version>$version</version>
                <authors>CME</authors>
                <owners>CME</owners>
                <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
                <description>$filepath</description>
            </metadata>
            <files>
                <file src=""$id.dll"" target=""$target""/>
            </files>
            </package>"
            return $x
        }
        CreateNewNuspec > $env:temp "$id-$version.xml"

        Return $retCode
    }
}

$retVal = CreateNugetPackage $File
exit $retVal
}
```

It's not the cleanest code but this is my first time coding in powershell

Comment: Is this the same function used here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448560/creating-a-function-that-writes-to-a-file-in-powershell

Comment: Yes it is, if it would help I can post the entirety of the code

Comment: yes definitely so we can see how it evolved. Also post what `$env:TEMP` points to, normally it's just your temp folder. Also post the error message.

Comment: At `CreateNewNuspec > $env:temp "$id-$version.xml"` what are the values of $id and $version? Also you are writing to a file, shouldn't it be `CreateNewNuspec > $env:temp+"\"+"$id-$version.xml"`

Comment: "$id-$version.xml" outputs "AjaxControlToolkit-3.5.50401.xml" and I tried "CreateNewNuspec > $env:temp+"\"+"$id-$version.xml"" but it was denied again

Comment: do you have access to $env:temp? what does it point to?

Comment: I should have access to the folder, it is pointing to the temp folder within my user folder

Comment: Can you post the exact error, with the extra few lines that come with it ? it could be something within the function generating this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so credit to this goes to Micky Balladelli for his much appreciated help! He suggested

```
$env:temp+"\"+"$id-$version.xml"
```

but that didn't work. What did work though was placing that within a variable, so I made a variable to hold what Micky suggested

```
$OutputFile = $env:temp+"\"+"$id-$version.xml"
```

and at the bottom of the code I called the function

```
CreateNewNuspec > $OutputFile
```

and that resolved the issue entirely